# How to use promise in order to wait for a function to execute

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I have an async piece of javascript code that need to execute and then the next statements can be executed

```js
function getEventData() {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
              eventList.forEach((event) => {
                db.collection('Events').doc(event)?.collection('registeredStudents')?.get()
                .then((querySnapshot) => {
                  eventData.push({"id": event, "number": querySnapshot.size})
                })
              })
              resolve();
            })
          }
          getEventData().then(console.log(eventData))
```

`eventList` is an array with 17 elements and it list through the database around 17 times, that is inefficient but I had no choice so had to do like that. Anyways in the console I get an empty array logged. How do I solve that. PS: I am new to async javascript and promises.

Comment: Sending multiple async requests in a loop can cause issues. You'll need to use something like `Promise.all(...)` to ensure all promises are fulfilled.

Comment: I am a little new to async. how to I make sure the console log statement run after all the promises get resolved as `.then` statement doesn't seem to work

Comment: I have updated my answer with a snippet that shows what your function should resemble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to deal with your problem is not using new Promise with resolve, yet by using async await.
When you await a promise, it waits for it to resolve and returns the result (not a promise!) before continuing to the next line.
A function awaiting a promise returns a promise when called.
Promise.all combines multiple promises to one, so you can wait for multiple promises to resolve all at once, and have them run at the same time (async).

```
async function getEventData(eventList) {
    try {
        const eventData = [];

        await Promise.all(eventList.map(async event => {
            const querySnapshot = await db.collection('Events').doc(event)?.collection('registeredStudents')?.get();
            eventData.push({"id": event, "number": querySnapshot.size});
        }));
        
        console.log(eventData)
    } catch (exception) {
      // error handling
    }
}
```

Comment: async/await keywords are simply syntactic sugar for promises. It's the exact same thing..

Comment: @MattOestreich, your right - its the exact same thing, but its more advanced and recommended. Its shorter, more elegant, more readable and easier to handle.

Comment: So then saying the problem is not using async/await is misleading. Async/await has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: since `Promise.all` is being used so, a promise needs to be generated somewhere to get resolved. in the above code where is the promise getting generated?

Comment: The `get()` method is what returns the promise. From here - `db.collection('Events').doc(event)?.collection('registeredStudents')?.get();`

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple demo of how to use promises in a loop. The async operation I am performing is "sleeping" (aka nothing happens until everything has "slept")..

```js
const sleepTimes = [1, 2, 3];
const promises = [];

sleepTimes.forEach(time => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return setTimeout(resolve, time * 1000, time * 1000);
  });
  promises.push(promise);
});

console.log(promises);

Promise.all(promises).then((values) => {
  document.body.innerHTML = values;
});
```

Which would mean your function should look something like:

```js
function getEventData() {
  const promises = [];
  eventList.forEach((event) => {
    // I assume this already returns a promise, so there's no need to wrap it in one
    const promise = db.collection("Events").doc(event)?.collection("registeredStudents")?.get();
    promises.push(promise);
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
}

getEventData().then((values) => console.log(values));
```

Comment: Just a clarification `values` is an array that is just returned by the function `getEventData`. In other words, it is just the array `promises`

Comment: It should be an array of values that each promise returned.

Comment: okay so as far as I understood the array `promises` that you have declared at the top contains the resolved promises from the line `Promise.all(promises)`. after calling the function `getEventData().then((value) => console.log(value))` the `value` contains the value each `promises = []` return?

Comment: Nope. The array `promises` is an array of unfulfilled promises. It just gathers all promises you want to fulfill. The `Promise.all(promises)` is what will actually fulfill each promise. For example if you do `const p = new Promise((res, rej) => res());` and then `console.log(p)` you'll see it just logs a Promise object. Thats essentially all we are doing in the promises array - collecting the Promise object from each event, then the Promise.all() is what will actually fulfill our promises and return values. (keep in mind this is at a high level)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Promise.all()`:

```js
function getEventData() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    await Promise.all(
      eventList.map(async (event) => {
        let querySnapshot = await db.collection('Events').doc(event)?.collection('registeredStudents')?.get()
        eventData.push({"id": event, "number": querySnapshot.size})
      })
    );
    resolve();
  })
}

getEventData().then(console.log(eventData))
```

Comment: I am not really sure that .then will execute after all the promises are resolved. I am still getting an empty array after using that. where as when I console log within the map loop I am getting what I need.

Comment: There may be a problem with the api response. @Vaibhav07